# Move button click event function in to other class in visual studio? - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, user-interface

How can I have a custom class ex. named `Inputs` and have all my winForm button clicks and Ui elements events in it rather then having it in the main form class?

Currently I would have this in the main form class, but I want to move it to another class.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // Do something
    }
```

Comment: You write the `Do Something` logic in the class methods and call those methods from the event handlers in the from.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I know I can have a method in a class and then in the "button click function" that is in the main form just have `Inputs.button1Click()` but I don't want to have the button click function in the main form.

Comment: why not? The click-handling function is not much use anywhere else, since it's specific to that button in that form. In the form code is _exactly_ where it belongs. It's not re-usable, so what advantage is there to putting it into a separate class? You can, as Chetan suggested, move any _processing_ which results from the click into a separate class, but the click-handling function itself belongs in the form, even if all it contains is a call to another method. The WinForms framework doesn't permit you to define it anywhere else, but as I've explained, you don't need to anyway.

Comment: @ADyson well let's say if I have a lot of Ui elements and I would like to keep my code a bit less messy, it would be nice to be able to place the all Ui handling and keyboard inputs in its own class if possible.

Comment: how does that reduce the mess? You still have the same number of methods. And now they're all in one class, so every single change to the UI in every form affects that one class, so you have a potential  maintenance headache, and you also have one huge class where it might start to be hard to remember which method belongs to which UI element, and which form it relates to. If code isn't re-usable, like event-handling functions aren't. then putting it into the context where it's actually used is the less messy thing, I'd say.

Comment: It's ultimately a matter of opinion I guess, but your assertion that it reduces mess is not particularly logical, in my own view. Separation of UI interaction and business logic is a sensible separation of concerns to aim for, though. That way you can re-use business logic in different UI (and non-UI) contexts. Anyway the point is moot because simply you can't physically do it in WinForms. The best you can do is write `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      SomeClass.DoWorkAsAResultOfButton1Click();
    }` within your form, so it's the most minimal it can be.

Comment: @ADyson Ok fine you have convinced me, I'll instead just move my main program in to its own class and in the main form just have a single method call in the Form ui functions .I just thought it looked kind of dumb having a bunch of button_click(), with just a single method call in it, like there would be a better way of doing it instead of calling a function that only calls another single function.

Comment: Actually it's not so unusual for a form to be a relatively thin layer like that. The only other code you might have in there is code which then gets the result of your method call, and updates that specific UI accordingly. The other method call should, IMO, simply process data and return a result, and not concern itself with form-specific things like changing the content of textboxes etc. That's the job of the code inside the form, because it's unique to that form. That way you if you have a method to, say, insert data into a DB, you can re-use that in another form without changing it.

Comment: Note that the [tag:visual-studio] tag description says *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."* Please [edit] your question to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based on [@Spool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5402940/spool) 's answer, that works the way I originally imagined it.

*(However I am not sure it's the actually solution I will use)* :

**In main Form1 class:**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace InputFormTest
{
    public partial class mainForm : Form
    {
        public mainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeInputs();
        }

        void InitializeInputs()
        {
            InputHandler.mainForm = this;
            InputHandler.debugBox = debugBox;
            InputHandler.mainForm.Controls["button1"].Click += InputHandler.OnButton1Click;
            InputHandler.mainForm.Controls["button2"].Click += InputHandler.OnButton2Click;
            ((NumericUpDown)InputHandler.mainForm.Controls["numUpDown1"]).ValueChanged += InputHandler.OnNumUpDown1Changed;
        }
    }
}
```

**And the InputHandler Class:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace InputFormTest
{
    public static class InputHandler
    {
        public static Form mainForm;
        public static RichTextBox debugBox;

        public static void OnButton1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            debugBox.AppendText("Button1 Clicked \n");
        }

        public static void OnButton2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            debugBox.AppendText("Button2 Clicked \n");
        }

        public static void OnNumUpDown1Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            debugBox.AppendText($"Num value: {((NumericUpDown)sender).Value} \n");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: WinForm Screenshot]

**[Download VS Project](http://www.patan77.com/download/InputFormTest.zip)**

Comment: Yes that looks about right for what you were asking for. Now, I wouldn't use this for a serious project. If you are just learning WinForms or just trying things out. That's fine, nothing wrong with this. But, if this is anything you plan on using in a project of more importance I would use [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/). Or make my own UI framework. Preferably using WPF but still. Rolling your own is always an option.

Comment: I was thinking to use something like this to implement a custom user control which can either be dumb (no user mouse or key interactions) or interactive (implements user interactions).  The user interactions are so complex, I am tempted to create a separate Navigator class, which given a Map (model), gives feedback to the user.  I could pass the events through from the user control or I could handle them as done here.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a couple different ways you could do this. But you could skip the entire auto generated Click handlers and define your own as to avoid another level of Method calling. A very naive way to do it would be something like this:

```
public class FormInputHandler
{
    private Form1 _form1;

    public FormInputHandler(Form1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
        _form1.Controls["button1"].Click += Button1ClickHandler;
    }

    private void Button1ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Granted I wouldn't necessarily do this exactly. But I think it demonstrates the point. It's kind of what you are trying to do. This way you don't have to have the all the Handler Methods in your Form1 class file. Then to use something like this just do:

(Inside your `private void InitializeComponent()` Method in your `Form1.Designer.cs`)

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // 
        // button1
        // 

        // Generated button1 stuff goes here.

        // 
        // Form1
        // 

        // Generated Form1 stuff goes here

        // Call this at the end so that 
        // everything is already added to the form.
        AttachInputHandler();
    }

    #endregion

    private void AttachInputHandler()
    {
        this._inputHandler = new FormInputHandler(this);
    }

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private FormInputHandler _inputHandler;
```

Comment: Just to clarify, don't copy this code and use it. It was written very quickly off the top of my head to demonstrate the *concept* of moving EventHandler assignment and deceleration to a separate file.

Comment: Do not modify manually the `InitializeComponent()` in 'designer' file. This is a tool-generated part that the VisualStudio's Form Designer has later to read, parse, and understand, and even execute parts of that in design-time in proper order. If you damage something, you may later get nasty surprise, including loss of code written in Designer.cs, both original and your additions. If you use any form of code versioning regularly, that may rescue you. If not, you're screwed. I've seen complex forms evaporating just because the Form Designer did not understand a typo in InitializeComponent.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl 
"Just to clarify, don't copy this code and use it. It was written very quickly off the top of my head to demonstrate the concept"

Comment: You always get a constructor that calls InitializeCompoent(). So, for things you cannot click/edit in the Designer, instead of modifying InitializeComponent, just add your fixups or additions right in the ctor, right after that call.

Comment: This is nothing but moving mess from one place to another. As soon as the id or name of Control1 changes things will break apart. So it actually creates more issues then it solves

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya

Yes I completely agree. But OP asked *How to do it* they did not ask "Is this a good thing to do?" Or "Is this good a good practice?" They asked *how to actually do it* which I supplied an answer to.

Comment: @Spool true in a literal sense, and your answer does achieve that, but OTOH is it really all that useful to facilitate the implementation of something which is a bad idea in the first place? Far better, surely, to point out that it's not a great concept.

Comment: This is actually the answer I was originally looking for, I had looked at custom click event handling.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, which I have done. Multiple times. I don't know why OP is trying to do this nor do I know what the intention is. Maybe they are just playing around with some ideas. Or maybe they have a situation where something like this is the only viable option for some unknown reason. In both cases. The answer to how do it along with the warning of the issues that come with it is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

Create your `input` class and define your method (the parameters and the return value have to be acceptable to the event!)

```
static class input
{    
    public static void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
}
```

Then go to your `From1` or whatever your `MainForm` is.

And then add it (I recommend in the `InitializeComponent();` method or in the constructor)

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(171, 50);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

        // Here you add the event handler
        this.button1.Click += input.button1_Click;

        //...
    }
```

And you're done!

Hope this helps.